# Slim 3 with Eloquent ORM - Relationships not exist on collection

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, relational-database

I have a problem with Eloquent relationships in my Slim 3 based application. The goal is return $data to view. When I try that:

```
use App\Models\Favorite as F;
$favs = F::where('user_id',$_SESSION['user_id'])->get()->offer;

foreach($favs as $offer)
{
    //  not important now...
}

return $data;
```

I am getting an error:
Property [offer] does not exist on this collection instance.
I made relations in my Offer and Favorite models:

```
public function offer() // in Favorite model
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Offer', 'offer_url');
}

public function favorite() // in Offer model
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Favorite', 'url');
}
```

In database we can see tables: offers (with url column) and favorites (with offer_url column).

How to make that relationships working?

Please for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get method return a Collection instance, not Favorite.

Use:

```
$favs = F::where('user_id', $_SESSION['user_id'])->get();
```

then:

```
foreach($favs as $favorite) {
   $offer = $favorite->offer;
}
```

And don't forget to use eager loader: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading